# Log every stored procedure call in a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way we can log every call of stored procedure in a table with stored procedure parameter?

Like we call a stored procedure with 3 parameters, can we get the stored procedure name and all the parameters with their values?

If we execute command:

```
exec USP_GetEvents 7,0,1,null
```

this will return a result on a front but in the backside will log in to a table with parameter and execution time success or fail

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could get something up and running with SQL Server **Extended Events** to do this. See [this quickstart guide for Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to get started

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler can log the successful execution of a stored procedure to a table.

Open SQL Server profiler and check off "Save to table".  Pick the database and table you would like to results to log to.

[image]

Next, under the "Events Selection" tab, select the following columns

- TextData
- SPID (required)
- Duration (units are milliseconds in the GUI and microseconds if logged to a table or file)

[image: Profiler Event Selection]

If set up correctly you'll be able to see stored procedure execution results.  I executed the following query on my local machine and pasted the results below.

```
EXEC [Website].[SearchForPeople] @SearchText = 'Aa', @MaximumRowsToReturn = 10
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Btw, on `DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(50) = 'Aa', @MaximumRowsToReturn INT = 10 EXEC [Website].[SearchForPeople] @SearchText, @MaximumRowsToReturn` this does not show the values of the local variables so the trace does not include the **values** of the actual arguments (only the text of EXEC statement).